# convert char dictionary to string dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, count

I have been given a homework with the following statement:

> Write a program which counts all characters in a string except space (' '). 
>   Print all occurrences in the following format:
>
> ```
> {char} -> {occurrences}
> ```

I wrote the program in char, but i keep getting a timeout error when i submit it in their homework-system. Here is my code:

```
SortedDictionary<char, int> text = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();
char[] characters = Console.ReadLine() 
    .Where(x => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(x))
    .ToArray();
foreach (var character in characters)
{
    if (text.ContainsKey(character))
    {
        text[character]++;
    }
    else
    {
        text.Add(character, 1);
    }
}
foreach (var character in text.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{character.Key} -> {character.Value}");
}
```

I can't get my head around on how to read it as a string and still get the result. Here is an example:

```
"text text text" = t -> 6 e -> 3 x -> 3
```

Comment: Assuming you only have to worry about ASCII, just create an array of integers with 256 elements. Use the character (1 byte) as an index into the array to increment/recover the count. Will be much faster than a SortedDictionary.

Comment: The exercise is to be done with a dictionary and the ASCII wont be necessary. It should count how many times a character occures in a given string.

Comment: Can you clarify: does the assignment dictate the use of a Dictionary? SortedDictionary? Or is it your evaluation that you can avoid ASCII by using a Dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure your expectation, but if you use string instead of char array can improve performance a little bit:

```
            var text = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();
            var inputText = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (var character in inputText)
            {
                if (character == ' ')
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (text.ContainsKey(character))
                {
                    text[character]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    text.Add(character, 1);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood you correctly, all you need is to get your output right.
This should do the trick:

```
foreach (var character in text.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value))
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}->{1}", character.Key, character.Value));
}
```